# Unwrap Text Cell permanently

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice

When I use LibreOffice Calc in Ubuntu 20.04, I am not able to expand a paragraph so that it looks always like this :

[image]

Instead, it always looks like this with the little arrow on the right :

[image]

I would like it stays unwrap permanently as in the first picture.

How can I fix that?

Comment: There is an option to automatically wrap text, but this will also expand the cell height to fit the text in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Format - Cells" dialog, uncheck "Wrap text automatically" on the "Alignment" tab. All text will be displayed, unless a cell to the right is not empty.

Cell height will be adapted if your cell contains hard returns, which you can enter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you do not want the cell height to be automatically adjusted, then set the row height. You can do so with Format - Rows - Height. Check the "Default value" tickmark before hitting OK if you wish the cell to have the default height: that will fill out the correct value, which you then can apply hitting the OK button.